# Parsing JSON from URL and then getting values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, parsing

So, the previous issue with parsing JSON from URL has been solved and it works just fine. Now I'm trying to get JSON from different URL and it doesn't seem to work again.

I tried the way I made the previous URL work, but it's not working for this one. Here's the code I have:

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Get JSON from URL - Test</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1-rc2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="testjson"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
var scmAPI = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=440&market_hash_name=Strange%20Australium%20Grenade%20Launcher";

  $.getJSON(scmAPI, function(json) {
    document.getElementById("testjson").innerHTML = "Price: " + json.lowest_price;
  });
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPYzOR

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: JavaScript cannot make requests to third party domains due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), unless JSONP or CORS are supported by the request recipient. If they are not, you may need to use a server-side proxy to make the request for you

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API/Feedback#API_Considerations_for_Web_Developers)  JSONP is not supported by the API, which means that you will have to fetch the data from a server to fetch the data for you.

Comment: So.. What should I use to get the data then?

Comment: What kind of server are you using on the backend?

Comment: If you're using an Apache server with PHP, you can make a self-hosted file with a CURL request to the api, and then return the data from here to your JavaScript. It works because you technically obatin the data through the same server (where your other html/js is stored).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work around you can use is to add `http://crossorigin.me/` before your URL to basically get around CORS. So your full URL will be `http://crossorigin.me/http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=440&market_hash_name=Strange%20Australium%20Grenade%20Launcher`

Here's an example of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/r6g56xss/

Edit: Though the best way would be, like others have said, to make the request on the server and then pass the data to the client once it receives the response.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it on an Apache server:

Create a file, for example gateway.php with these contents:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
curl_exec($ch);
```

And replace the 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/' part in your JS with 'gateway.php'

It will return the data obatined from the steam community domain, but throug a self-hosted php file, which is not against JavaScript's cross domain policy.